# Drawing heatmap on top of candlestick chart

Tags: reactjs, plotly, heatmap, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to draw a heatmap (canvas or svg) on top of a candlestick chart so I can see volume or orderbook size for that particular candle (simular to what tensorcharts and bookmap do). Right now I'm looking at using existing libraries like react-highstock, echarts, plotly, anycharts but can't find any examples with heatmaps over existing charts.

I've also tried manually drawing the canvas on top of the candlestick chart but not sure how to determine the X Y coordinates of the point where the heatmap should be drawn. Have searched on github repos, google and here. I'm looking for examples or libraries that support this with documentation. Thanks!

Comment: You can't just take any other libary and draw "other" an existing canvas/svg. I'm afraid you have to draw it by yourself or use a chart who supports this. E.g. tradingview.com offers contract based libaries; Another good (open-source) libary is techan-js. The only bad thing about techan-js is that the draw is based on price and timeline => you can't just slide the chart and you can't use reponsivnes this way. tradingview.com is the easiest way if you want to save 100th hours of development time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajmond, I've already sorted it out and have a working solution

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved this, I found a couple of libraries that allowed drawing a heatmap but they were very limited in how much you could draw and quickly bottlenecked. The final solution was to use a charting library that allowed you to get the X Y coordinates for each price/time and then layer a canvas over (or underneath) it.